# La función de seguimiento de preguntas y respuestas está activa

Tags: discusión, anuncios, seguir-publicación

Estamos felices de anunciar que la función de seguimiento de preguntas y respuestas [previamente anunciada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions) está ahora activa a través de la red, incluyendo Stack Overflow, todos los sitios de Stack Exchange y todos los sitios Meta.

Puedes seguir cualquier pregunta o respuesta (que no hayas escrito tú) haciendo clic en el botón [seguir] que se muestra en el menú inmediatamente debajo del mensaje (junto al botón [compartir]):

> [image: Obtener actualizaciones de preguntas y respuestas]

Después de haber seguido una publicación, recibirás notificaciones en tu buzón de entrada para todas las nuevas respuestas (en el caso de que haya seguido una pregunta), comentarios, ediciones y avisos. No recibirás notificaciones de ninguna acción que hayas realizado. Como se mencionó en la publicación anterior, en este momento no estamos realizando cambios en las notificaciones recibidas por el propietario de una publicación o debido a @menciones.

La publicación inicial había sido planeada para incluir sólo el seguimiento de preguntas. Gracias a muchas personas que han colaborado en las últimas semanas, estamos felices de publicar el seguimiento de preguntas y respuestas al mismo tiempo. Estos están disponibles tanto en la vista normal como en la móvil.

Todavía estamos planeando dos publicaciones más relacionadas:

1. **Pestaña de perfil de seguimientos y el filtro del listado de preguntas**: Una pestaña para los seguimientos se añadirá a la página de actividad de tu perfil de usuario. Cada usuario podrá ver esta pestaña que proporcionará un listado de las preguntas y respuestas seguidas, con tipos de ordenación estándar, y la posibilidad de dejar de seguir desde el listado. Los usuarios (con excepción de los moderadores y el personal autorizado) no podrán ver esta información sobre otros usuarios (ni se hará pública en la API, la SEDE o los volcados de datos). Adicionalmente, se añadirá un filtro en el desplegable [más] de la página de listado de Preguntas para "Seguidas".
2. **Renombraremos la característica de Favoritos a Marcadores**. Como mencionamos en la publicación de anterior, la característica será la misma que la de Favoritos, con el nombre y el icono actualizados para representar con mayor precisión las expectativas y el uso del usuario. Y podrás tanto "añadir a marcadores" como "seguir" una pregunta.

Esperamos que esta nueva característica os permita tener un mejor acceso al contenido que te interesa y que deseas seguir.

---

<sub>Traducción de la publicación original en Meta.SE ([The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/346768))</sub>