# Hagamos que el texto "No estás siguiendo ninguna publicación." apunte a la explicación propia de Meta SOes, no a la inglesa

Tags: característica-nueva, traducciones, interfaz-de-usuario, seguir-publicación

En [el perfil de cada uno](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current) aparece la sección *Publicaciones seguidas*. Si resulta que no sigues nada, te sale el texto:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> No estás [siguiendo ninguna publicación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network).

El enlace apunta al artículo de Meta.SE [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/209901). Sin embargo, tenemos una versión en castellano de esta publicación, la que publicó Pikoh en [La función de seguimiento de preguntas y respuestas está activa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4666/83).

¿Podría cambiarse el enlace?

El texto aparece en http://es.traducir.win con la cadena:

> [No estás [siguiendo ninguna publicación]($helpLink$).](https://es.traducir.win/strings/16130)

Pero no sé cómo se modifica la variable `$helpLink`.

Comment: Interesante.. en la semana pregunto a Gerv, si eso es posible o si necesitamos un CM...