# Agregar notificaciones a tus votos negativos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Una de las grandes desventajas de votar negativamente es que las personas no suelen retirar sus votos negativos una vez que la pregunta/respuesta se editó. Gran parte se debe al motivo de que no te enteras que ya fue corregido (O al menos a mí nunca me ha llegado una notificación y me entero una vez que vuelvo a entrar al post).

Creo que es importante que este sitio tenga esta característica, porque contribuiría a una mayor interacción de los usuarios. Evitando que los votos negativos se conserven, e incluso si se corrigió correctamente impulsaría a un voto positivo (que en lo personal creo que es importante pues hay pocos votos en SOes)

¿Se podría solicitar esta característica?

Comment: Si que se puede!! obviamente, hay que pedirlo en meta.se... algo asi, seria para toda la red...

Comment: o se puede agregar la opción a una extensión ... buena idea Ed

Comment: Pues estuve revisando en Meta.se, hay ya algunas preguntas que han pedido esta característica o muy similar, sin embargo, la comunidad de meta.se rechaza la idea por que se llenaría de "basura" nuestro buzón de notificaciones. Me atreví a mencionar el tema de nuevo con los puntos de vista que proponía, de igual manera fue rechazada la idea y decidí borrar esa publicación...

Comment: tu idea esta buena para una extensión no para el flujo de datos que maneja SE ... normalmente la preguntas que piden cosas o que estan relacionadas al sistema de votos negativos son rechazadas por la comunidad ya que se indica que lleva 15 años funcionando y esperfecta ..

Comment: El botón Seguir o Follow  teóricamente enviaría una notificación ante una edición de la pregunta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network

Comment: @Emeeus lo has probado???

Comment: Si, jamás recibí una notificación. Quizá porque justo no cambió nada de nada.

Comment: @Emeeus el problema es que yo como usuario quiero seguir preguntas que me parezcan interesantes, para tener un acceso rápido y poder guardarlas para no perderles rastro, no quisiera que mi apartado de preguntas que sigo esté llena de preguntas o respuestas mal hechas. Simplemente me gustaría que opcionalmente pudieras configurar tu buzón para que se te muestre "Se ha modificado una respuesta a la que has votado negativamente, ¿Quieres reconsiderar tu voto?" O algo parecido

Comment: @EduardoJiménez eso si se puede y existe en favoritos: https://i.imgur.com/CArPC6y.jpg

Comment: @Emeeus es a lo que me refiero yo tengo toneladas de favoritos y jamás he recibido una notificación de algo que se haya editado ... por ese motivo y otros estoy haciendo una extensión ... que haga mas facil dar el apoyo y que sea un apoyo de calidad ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Creo que no se ha entendido, lo que me refiero es que su solución es agregar a favoritos todas las preguntas para que me notifique cuando hayan sido editadas, mi respuesta es que yo no quiero seguir (agregar a favoritas) todas las preguntas o respuestas "mal hechas".

Comment: @EduardoJiménez no, me refiero a que ***existe***, no he dicho que sea la solución adecuada para los votos negativos; si ves por el mismo motivo estoy desarrollando una extensión ...

Answer (score 1):

*Me parece correcto el planteamiento* **Parcialmente**

Es muy cierto que la herramienta de votos es funcional y cumple con los objetivos que fue diseñada. Pero también es cierto que carece de feedback para quienes emiten un voto.
cuando pienso en el feedback a quienes emiten el voto, pienso en los mismo, ***como se cuando un POST es editado?***

Independientemente del motivo del voto: no sabemos si el POST mejoro en algún momento o empeoro ... por lo tanto no hay una facilidad para re-evaluar el contenido del post y el Voto dado... a menos que el votante Visite continuamente el POST en cuestión.

El problema esta en la plataforma... un feedback para los usuarios a partir de un voto, es un gasto de recursos innecesario; ya que si se implementa algo parecido, emitir una notificación; cosa que el al usuario podría pasar desapercibido. entonces desde el punto de vista de la red SE no es rentable. (eso opino yo)

***Ahora hablemos sobre los tipos de votos:***

**Votos de Cierre:**

- el que emite este voto no se puede retractar en el momento que lo desee.
- si el post esta mal estructurado y le dan vostos de cierre (2); y es editado, los votantes nunca se dan por enterado, incluso si cae el tercer voto, se aplica el cierre a la pregunta, aunque previamente haya sido editada y mejorada.

**Votos Negativos:**

- el único punto aquí es que al emitir un voto negativo pueden existir muchas razones, [la comunidad tiene un link relacionado al por que se emiten votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo). y es cierto aquí tampoco hay un feedback para el votador negativo cuando el post es editado.

***nota:***
no voy a ahondar en el uso de los votos negativos o de cierre, su objetivo ha sido discutido hasta la saciedad y lo mínimo que podemos hacer como comunidad es aportar a que se le de un correcto uso a las herramientas, aunque existan usuarios que no lo hagan.

***Propuesta:***

No estoy seguro si exista alguna extensión que ya lo haga, pero yo estoy en el desarrollo de una extensión que permitirá hacer tracking a los POST que se desee incluyendo aquellos que hayas votado o no, favoritos o a los usuarios que consideres tu amigos y suelen publicar cosas en el sitio, similar al agregar como favorito; pero buscando detectar si este post fue Actualizado y obtener una notificación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto ya existe: [La función de seguimiento de preguntas y respuestas está activa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4666/83)

Comment: "*el que emite este voto no se puede retractar en el momento que lo desee*". Sí que se puede.

Comment: Que desde tu punto de vista se esté haciendo un "mal uso" de los votos negativos, es muy subjetivo. Yo creo que votar negativamente una pregunta que no está en la comunidad correcta, que busca que le hagan los ejercicios o que sencillamente no aporta nada porque hay 10 preguntas iguales planteadas de manera ligeramente diferente y esta en concreto demuestra 0 trabajo de investigación es un uso más que correcto. Y votar negativamente a quienes responden ese tipo de preguntas, apoyando así el que aparezcan más, también.

Comment: @Benito-B tu como que no lees las publicaciones; indique que no voy a ahondar en el uso que cada quien le de a los votos ... y en ningún momento he dicho que el uso de los votos este mal. hay post que están excepcionalmente mal hechos y los usuarios son viejos... a esos les casco el comentario y el voto negativo, pero no es una necesidad ... te agradecería que conversaciones sobre el uso de votos los lleves al chat, no uses mis respuestas para hacer comentarios polémicos que realmente no aportan nada a mejorar el post.

Answer (score -1):

Si alguien está votando negativamente a una publicación que está mal hecha, está votando mal.

El voto negativo no es para enviar el mensaje "*tu publicación necesita ser corregida*", para eso está la sección de comentarios y la herramienta de cierre. El voto negativo es para enviar el mensaje "*tu publicación es mala*".

Comment: Pero entonces ¿cuál es la linea que separa "debe ser corregida" y "mala"? Hay publicaciones que si no la corrige el autor son malas....hasta que la corrige. Por ejemplo una pregunta que no aporta código es mala pero más tarde puede el autor añadirlo. ¿Entiendo así que debe crear una pregunta nueva con un titulo repetido? Puede llevarle más de un día corregir su pregunta. O puede que no la corrija jamás (y el voto negativo es válido). Yo tambien estoy a favor de poder al menos poder elegir si quieres que te notifiquen o no

Comment: No estoy hablando de la distinción entre pregunta mala y pregunta corregible si no de la utilidad de los votos negativos. Si quieres que una pregunta se corrija: Comenta y vota para su cierre. Si crees que la pregunta es mala: vota negativo.

Comment: ¿Puedes aclararme la diferencia entre "votar para su cierre" y "votar negativo"? Ambas me parecen ambiguas y pregunto con legítimo interés, no con sarcasmo. :thumbup

Comment: Si quieres comunicar que la pregunta debe (y puede) ser corregida, escribe en los comentarios las correcciones que crees que se necesitan y vota para que la pregunta sea cerrada (así evitas que reciba respuestas). Si quieres comunicar que la pregunta es mala, vota negativo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no has entendido la publicación del usuario... si quieres podemos debatir el tema en el chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Más razón para no emitir votos negativos. No me gusta la idea de decirle a un usuario "tu publicación es mala" (a menos que esté bien seguro de que se lo merezca, lo cual es raro de ver).

Comment: cuando una publicacion es mala yo prefiero comentarle como arreglarla...